# When does a Reliable Proxy terminate in Akka?

Tags: akka

The [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/reliable-proxy.html) says:

> When the target actor terminates, the proxy will terminate as well

I am confused about what happens when:

1. The remote machine crashes
2. The remote node is unreachable due to network issues

What happens in these situations? Does the proxy only terminate if the target shuts down properly and is able to get off a Terminate message? If a proxy does not terminate under these conditions, how can a system using a reliable proxy recover from a network or remote machine failure?

Answer (score 0):

As of Akka 2.2 `ReliableProxy` will stop itself under the conditions you describe due to [Remote Deathwatch](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/remoting.html#Watching_Remote_Actors).  The `ReliableProxy` watches the tunnel and stops itself after receiving `Terminated` for the tunnel.

In Akka 2.3 I've contributed an [enhancement](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.0-RC1/contrib/reliable-proxy.html#Connecting_to_the_target) where `ReliableProxy` will try to reconnect to the target after it terminates (it does not do this in Akka 2.2, it just stops). We are using this enhanced `ReliableProxy` in production.

Comment: The reconnect feature is now in Akka 2.3-RC1.